# Python if loop doesn't function/repeats ineffectively

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, if-statement

```
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")  
userGuess = int(input("Your guess: "))   
import random      
randomNumber = (random.randint(1,100))

found = False

while userGuess in range(1,100):  
if userGuess > randomNumber:  
   int(input("Guess lower: "))  
   found = False  
elif userGuess < randomNumber:   
    int(input("Guess higher: "))  
    found = False  
else:  
    print("You got it!")      
    found = True
```

When guessing the number, after your first guess it will use the right higher/lower if/elif statement, but every guess thereafter will be looped back into whichever statement was used the first time. Ends up repeating the same thing even if i go out of range. I know theres a lot of these threads for this program but i couldn't figure out what my issue was, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't assign input to userGuess in loop

```
import random
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)
userGuess = int(raw_input("Your guess: "))


print randomNumber
found = False

while 1:
    if userGuess < 1 or userGuess >100:
        userGuess =  int(input("input between 1 and 100 "))
        continue
    if userGuess ==  randomNumber:
        print("You got it!")
        break
    userGuess =  int(input("Guess lower: ")) if userGuess < randomNumber else int(input("Guess higher: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **while** loop has no body.  Indent the compound **if** statement to make it the body of the loop, i.e.

```
while userGuess in range(1,100):  
    if userGuess > randomNumber:  
       int(input("Guess lower: "))  
       found = False  
    elif userGuess < randomNumber:   
        int(input("Guess higher: "))  
        found = False  
    else:  
        print("You got it!")      
        found = True
```

---

Once you have that, you'll need to fix your logic.  Most of all, you need to accept a new UserGuess after each wrong one.  Your loop statement should likely be

```
while not found:
```

The statement you have destroys the user's input value.

Comment: Thank you! You both helped me a lot

Comment: Great!  Thanks for remembering to accept an answer; that lets SO archive the issue.